# how to pull fixed number of items from mysql database

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an web application that when you go onto a page a ajax call is made to get all the data from the database. It stores the data into a Global variable and as the user scrolls down the page it loads more into the page. Now I would like to be able  to call the database and grab lets say 20 items from the database as they scroll down, instead of getting them all on the page load. Is there a good way of doing this? Thanks for any help.

here is what I would like to do
1.Page load (get first 20 items)
2.As they scroll down near bottom(Ajax call to get the next 20 and append it to table, list etc)

mysql help for the correct query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL supports the `LIMIT` keyword on [selects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), e.g.:

```
SELECT foo,bar
FROM   charlie
WHERE  criterion = value
LIMIT  20
```

It accepts up to two arguments. If you supply one, it's the number of rows (max) to return. If you supply two, the first is an offset (skip) value, and the second is a limit. E.g. (from the docs):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Combine `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY` and barring inserts, you have paging.

Comment: Then, for subsequent queries, you could try LIMIT 20, 20 and LIMIT 40, 20. When you provide two values to LIMIT, the first value is the starting offset. Alternatively you could pass an ID, and do WHERE `id` > (previous value)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the LIMIT option on the SELECT will do the trick. You'll obviously also need to keep track of the current position, and use the offset argument with LIMIT to make sure that you keep moving forward in the set.

LIMIT [offset], limit

So, after your query for the first 20, you'd need to store that position (20), and then use that as the offset:

LIMIT 20, 20

Then you'll need to increase the offset so that your limit is:

LIMIT 40, 20